# Capybara: Unable to find css

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using capybara to click a checkbox, however it can't seem to find it no matter what I do. I am able to correctly find both the span and the label inside the span, but not the input I actually need.

Here is the checkbox

```
<span class="checkbox tos">
  <input id="agreement" name="agreement" onclick="agreeValidate();" type="checkbox" value="false">
  <label for="agreement">I accept the <a href="http://www.dev.com:3000/terms" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>, <a href="http://www.dev.com:3000/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>, and am at least 13 years old</label>
</span>
```

And here are some of the things I have tried

```
page.check('agreement')
find(:css, '#agreement').set(true)
find('#agreement').set(true)
find('#agreement').click
```

However, they all give me the same error

```
Unable to find css "#agreement" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

I am also wondering will any of these methods fire off the `onclick` method, when the checkbox is clicked? I feel like `find(:css, '#agreement').set(true)` will not trigger the `onclick` event. However, I am not sure about the rest.

**Update**

I have also tried selecting the element through xpath. Here are the various things I have found out

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]')
```

This is able to find the `span` element no problem

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]/input')
```

This can't find the element I need, but this xpath correctly selects the element in chrome's console

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="agreement"]')
```

This can't find the element I need, but the xpath selects the element in chrome's console

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]/label')
```

This is able to find the `label` element in the `span` with no problem.

Comment: Please post more of your code. In isolation, it looks like `find('#agreement')` should work to find that checkbox, so if that's not working, there might be something wrong with the surrounding code (maybe it isn't loading the page correctly at all, or maybe there is invalid markup in the page).

Comment: What is the value of `Capybara.default_wait_time`?

Answer (score 41):

I had the exact issue yesterday.  Capybara was automatically ignoring the input due to it being invisible.  I solved it with the following:

```
find('#agreement', :visible => false).click
```

You can also add the following to env.rb to enable Capybara to interact with all hidden elements:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Comment: I tried check('#id', :visible => false) and Capybara raised 'Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' So the solution I came up with involved clicking the actual parent element that the user does see. Ideally Capybara does what your user does, so clicking on a non-visible element should be avoided.

Answer (score 10):

Try to add `:visible` option set to false.

```
find('#agreement', visible: false).click
```

By default Capybara finds only visible elements. It seems that underlying driver identified this input as invisible so it hasn't been found by Capybara.

`:visible` option is also supported by most of other Capybara methods (like `check`, `has_css?`, `have_selector`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this `page.execute_script("$('#agreement').attr('checked', true)")`. To make this work you should tag your examples with `js: true`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ... I tried the following it works fine ...

```
find('#tos', visible: false).set(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page is not being rendered because you're taken to some other page. To solve this, you don't need to change you're Capybara code. You will likely have to make some changes in your controller code.

I got this idea since you brought up in one of the comments that you are taken to your domain's internal server when doing `save_and_open_page` instead. Please provide me with the details of what you see in the internal server. Are there any error messages you see there? Also, please provide me with your code for the controller action of that view you want to check a checkbox on and any other code you defined that's called in that controller action.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell without seeing the whole HTML page.  Here are some possible problems:

1. You may be looking for the checkbox before the page is fully loaded?  Make sure you have enough wait time before calling `find(#agreement)`
2. You may have multiple tags with the same id="agreement".  Make sure you only have one.
3. Make sure the page is valid HTML.
4. Make sure the checkbox is visible, and enabled, and agreeValidate() is working properly.

Comment: 2 point is invalid. Capybara won't raise such error if there were multiple elements with such locator.

Comment: AFAIK it also shouldn't matter if input is enabled when `find` is invoked. It would matter if `click` is invoked but OP's code stops execution on `find`.